# Getting data from a new DbContext with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, dbcontext

I added a new DbContext to my project like this:

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("myapp_users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("myapp_roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("myapp_userroles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("myapp_userclaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("myapp_userlogins");
    }
}

[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("TestConnection")
    {
    }
    public static MyDbContext Create()
    {
        return new MyDbContext();
    }
}
```

But when I try to get some data with this command:

```
MyDbContext myContext = new MyDbContext();

var products = (from p in myContext.Products
                select p).ToList();
```

I have this error:

```
'MyDbContext' does not contain a definition for 'Products' and no extension method 'Products' accepting a first argument of type 'MyDbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any help on this? How can I get the data from a table in the database of a new context?

Comment: Where is the `IDbSet<Product> Products`?

Comment: @HristoYankov I don't have it. Should I create a new model for every table that I have in the DB?

Comment: I assume you are going 'code-first', correct? Then yes, you need a class `Product` and you have to add `public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }` in your db context class.

Comment: Oh wait, you already have a database? Do you still want to do code-first? Wouldn't adding an `EDMX` to your project be easier for you?

Comment: The code looks like the database tables are named different than the classes (Assuming the OnModelCreating method is correct). A line for the Product class needs to be added there too.

Comment: @JoseMMartin, seems like EDMX would be the easiest way for your project to integrate with an existing database, yes.

Comment: @HristoYankov ok I will do that. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what kind of database you use? Where the Prodict data are stored? The Dbcontext you use looks like the auto-generated context that you got when creating a new web application project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go code-first, you need a model for every entity, which will map (generate) to a database table. It usually means that the database will be generated based on your code, although there is the scenario where you have an existing database and you still go code-first.

i.e. you would need:

```
public class Product
{
  // ...
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  // ...

  public IDbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

If you do have an existing database, it might be easier for you to [add an `EDMX` to your project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx) and generate the context from it. Simply, you 'integrate' with an existing database instead of generating one.

Comment: I will use an EDMX then. Thank you for this!